# find a necessery and enough condition just using $\pi_{1}$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

> Suppose $p:\widetilde{X} \rightarrow X$ will be a covering space and $X$ is path connected and locally path connected, also $\widetilde{X}$ is connected, then find a necessary and enough condition only with using $\pi_{1}$ which for any open set $U \subset X$ , $p^{-1}(U)$ will be match in the definition of covering space.

---

1. I have no Idea what should I do to solve this problem.please help me with your knowledge
2. Also like some other problems in this branch,I can't imagine what is going on.
   if you know good source to solve my problem it will be great,I mean that some source which has a good illustration of what is happening through this definitions and concepts.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Regarding question 2, have you tried to read Allen Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*? It's available for free on his webpage. Otherwise I don't understand your question -- what does $p^{-1}(U)$ will be match in the definition of covering space" mean?

Comment: yes I have read hacher algebraic topology but I have this feeling that it is not appropriate for a person who this is a first time that is going to learn algebraic  topology.and I think it means that we can use $U$ instead $X$ in the definition of covering space.

Comment: Hatcher´s book is an introductory book in algebraic topology. Furthermore, I think that you want the lifting property for defining a covering. Search for "lifting property".